# Using state_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, form-helpers

I'm trying to use the state_select gem in my forms. It gives me the drop down and is says
state but there are no options to select.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br />
    <%= f.state_select :state, 'US', { :prompt => "State" }, { :style => "width: 75px;" } %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this format

```
state_select(object, method, country = "US", options = {}, html_options = {})
```

for you try this and use `your-object-name` and pass your `options`

```
<%= state_select(your-object-name, :state, country => 'US', options => {}, { :style => "width: 75px;" }) %>
```

**Source** : http://rubydoc.info/gems/state_select/0.1.0/frames